# Purpose of NTP vs. ICMP Timestamp message

Tags: icmp, ntp, clock-synchronization

I know the purpose of the Network Time Protocol is to synchronize clocks over networks, primarily with the use of the *Originate*, *Receive* and *Transmit* timestamps to make the time calculations.

But, the ICMP protocol **[also has](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Timestamp)** a Timestamp control message (and a respective Timestamp Reply one), that *"is used for time synchronization"*. It also contains three timestamp fields with the same name as in NTP, that are likely used in a similar manner.

So, what are the differences between the two? I guess the distinction is not that NTP is for desktop operating systems and ICMP for Layer 3 devices, since I know Cisco switches that are using NTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Timestamps may look like a similar field, but have different length and very different content

**ICMP**-timestamps' fields are 31-bit, carry relative-time of "touching" ICMP-packed on outgoing/incoming side of the network connection, expressed as a number of **miliseconds** elapsed since last UTC-midnight.
Highest order bit is used for flagging a UTC-uncoordinated host-time / non-standard value.

**NTP**-timestamps' fields are 64 bit, carry an absolute time, recorded as a 32-bit for seconds since epoch ( Jan-01-1900 .. till .. rollover in 2036 ) and another 32-bits for fractions of a second ( thus going in a time-measurement down to a **sub-nanosecond resolution** ).

Comment: Okay, so the content and time representation is different. But, for what purpose or goal ICMP Timestamp serves when NTP is there? For example, who uses it?

Comment: ICMP gets time-stamps from a packet round-trip transmission, to verify network associated transport-delays.